# How to recall jQuery animate function once animation completes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I am using following plugin.

[goalslider](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Beautiful-Goal-Progress-Slider-Plugin-With-jQuery-Goal-Slider/)

Now, what I am trying to do is ajax call will be made after some set interval and then this interval function will make the ajax call and get the new percentage to show some progress of the progressbar.

Like below:

```
 animateSteps: function() {
     //$(this.element).find('.jgs__step').addClass('box_highlight');    
  var $target = $(this.element).find('.jgs__steps-highlighted');
  var offsetValue = (Math.tan(this.settings.slantDegree * (Math.PI / 180)) * 100);
  var already_load = this.settings.alreadyLoad;
  //alert('start'+offsetValue);
  $({
      
    percentageValue: 0 - offsetValue
  }).animate({
    percentageValue: this.settings.percentage
  }, {
    duration: this.settings.duration,
    easing: this.settings.easing,
    step: function execStep() {
        console.log('now coming here...'+this.percentageValue);
        
        if(Math.round(this.percentageValue) >= already_load) {
          $target.css({
            'width': this.percentageValue + '%'
          });   
          
        } else {
          $target.css({
            'width': already_load+'%'//this.percentageValue + '%'
          });
          
        }
        
    //console.log(this.percentageValue);
      var conv = Math.round(this.percentageValue);
     // console.log(conv);
      if(conv == '0') {
          $('.step_one').css("box-shadow","0px 2px 12px 2px #fff");
      }
        if(conv == '26') {
            $('.step_one').css("box-shadow","none");
            $('.step_two').css("box-shadow","0px 2px 8px 3px #fff");
        }
        if(conv == '51') {
            $('.step_two').css("box-shadow","none");
            $('.step_three').css("box-shadow","0px 2px 8px 3px #fff");
        }
        if(conv == '76') {
            $('.step_three').css("box-shadow","none");
            $('.step_four').css("box-shadow","-12px 2px 14px -4px #fff");
        }
        
    },
    done: function(){
        console.log('i am done...');
        //call via ajax to get new percentage value.....
        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "get_newProgressNumber.php",
                data: {alreadyProgress: this.percentageValue},
                success: function(data) {
                    this.percentageValue + data; //so if progress is already at 25 so now try to reach 25+new percentage 35 = 60
                    //Not Working
                    this.animateSteps(); //callback to animate from 25 to 35 now but this is not working.
                    
                }, error: function() {
                    console.log('issue found');
                }
            });
        },5000);
    }
  });
  // $(this.element).find('.jgs__step').removeClass('box_highlight');
},
```

So anyone please suggest how I can make this happen? like if progressbar reach to 25 and then my ajax function bring new value like 35 so need to animate progress bar from 25 to 25+35 = upto 60.

Anyone knows?